# Binary search template for finding a double nearest to the key

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search

Is there template in C++ , which allows to find in a sorted vector the value nearest to the key, and returns its index (iterator). What I found, returns only a boolean.

Edited: The question was motivated by the fact that the binary search returns a boolean. I conclude that at the time returning the boolean, also the iterator is known. Returning it, I could find out *which* element is found. What is the reason that no such binary search is provided?.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Comment: You can write one. It's not too difficult.

Comment: If you don't want to sort container / array, `std::min_element` with good comparator should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want to avoid sorting yourc container / array, so I'm going to post most universal way. And the answer is – no. If you don't want to sort container, there's no ready template, but you can simply write your own function, like this:

```
template<typename iterator_t, typename value_t, typename comparator_t>
iterator_t nearest_element(iterator_t begin, iterator_t end, value_t value, comparator_t comparator) {
    return std::min_element(begin, end, [value, &comparator](double lhs, double rhs) {
        return comparator(std::abs(lhs - value), std::abs(rhs - value));
    });
}

template<typename iterator_t, typename value_t>
iterator_t nearest_element(iterator_t begin, iterator_t end, value_t value) {
    return nearest_element(begin, end, value, std::less<value_t>());
}
```

It's just simple math, nearest element is one with smallest absolute value of subtracting it from searched value. Code above still lets you change comparator (but hides subtraction / `std::fabs`) so it can be also used to find farthest value.

Usage (without specified comparator) is simple, like any other standard function:

```
std::vector<double> vec {2., 5., -4.};
auto it = nearest_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), -10.);
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```